# Regular expression for the following

Tags: java, regex

I have a tagged file which could have the following records #

```
<test> <code> abcd </code> </test>
<test> efgh </test>
```

How do I extract one piece of test tag at a time .. which means I want to extract the test tag in both the situations above, whether it has only content or other nested tags too ...

Comment: Even if you don't understand the formatting on StackOverflow, at least try to write all the necessary information in the plain text version of your question so that someone else can format it correctly for you.

Comment: To format it properly, edit your post, highlight what you want to be formatted, and then click the button with the 0s and 1s on it (the code button).  Alternatively indent it by 4 spaces (and make sure you have a blank line before it).

Comment: I edited it for now, edit it further if I'm wrong or if you need to clarify more.

Comment: After your edit your document resembles XML. Is it actually XML? If so perhaps you hsould consider using an XML parser instead of a regular expression for this task.

Comment: nope it is not an xml document ... it is a flat file and not a valid xml since attributes are missing quotes

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("<test>(.*?)</test>", Pattern.DOTALL);
```

This would fail, though, if `<test>` tags themselves can be nested (`<test> ... <test>...</test> ... </test>`).

The `?` makes the preceding `*` quantifier lazy, i. e. it will match as few characters as possible and therefore only match one tag at a time.

Comment: Tim, *VERY GOOD* for correctly noting the failure mode on minimal matching.  People always get that wrong. The way around the problem is to use `(?xs) <test> (?: (?! < /? test> ) . ) * </test>`. Yes, I know I left the start maximal. That’s ok.  Max-quantifiers usually run faster than min-quantifiers, and my look-ahead guarantees I won’t overrun it.

Answer (score 0):

Try the regular expression:

```
"\\bstart-tag:test\\s+(.*?)\\s+end-tag:test\\b"
```

The important point is that the `?` here means that the match should not be greedy, otherwise it can capture multiple tags.